# No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to install this `requirements.txt`:

```
tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
scipy==1.7.3
pillow==9.1.0
gdown
ubuntu
```

my `python` version is:

```
Python 3.8.10
```

my `pip3` version:

```
pip 20.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that this version of tensorflow is only available up to python version 3.7. As you can see [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/1.15.0/) under Programming Languages.